# How to point the domain name to VPS/dedicated server

Tags: wordpress, centos, vps, domain-name, virtualmin

I have a VPS/dedicated server which I have installed a wordpress site. I have bought a domain name from a local provider and now I need to point that domain name to my wordpress site when it is accessed from the browser. So far it can be accessed from the IP of the VPS.

The server has CentOS 7 and I have installed Virtualmin there and created a space with the name of my domain (abc.com), which is where the wordpress site is installed.

I have provided the following nameserver given by Virtualmin to my domain name provider but it does not seem to point to my server.

Virtualmin -> Server Configuration -> DNS Records -> Type=NS-Nameserver, Value="AB-C1234.defghij.kl56789.net."

I am new to this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your server must have IP address or ns records, just copy it from there. 
Add IP address in your domain registrar as A Record. 
and if find other details like cname, NS than can also add them but its enough to add point domain by using just IP as A Record.

Here is an example : 
Domain-name    Type        Value                 Propagation-Time
Domain.com    A Record    122.180.254           1 Hour